# Is there a list of test IMEI numbers somewhere?

Tags: testing, att, imei

When integrating with a credit card processor (such as Stripe, Auth.net, etc...), there is usually a list of valid and invalid test credit card numbers that a developer can use while building a system to ensure it works before going live.

Is there a similar list somewhere for IMEI numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Because I came here looking for a random IMEI for testing purposes:

```js
function generateIMEICode() {
  const randomDigits = Array.from({
    length: 14
  }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  document.getElementById("imei-number").innerHTML = randomDigits.join("") + checkDigit(randomDigits);
}

const checkDigit = (digits) => {
  let sum = digits.reduce((acc, digit, index) => {
    let doubledDigit = index % 2 === 0 ? digit : digit * 2;
    return acc + (doubledDigit > 9 ? doubledDigit - 9 : doubledDigit);
  }, 0);

  return (Math.ceil(sum / 10) * 10) - sum;
}

window.addEventListener('load', generateIMEICode());
```

```css
#imei-number {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="generateIMEICode();">Generate random test IMEI</button>
<p id="imei-number"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can't find a predetermined test list provided by a service provider then perhaps you can build your own test numbers list by using a random number generator against some valid known IMEI structure or perhaps reverse engineer the structure to check any input numbers are valid IMEI ones?

This link might help to understand the structure of IMEI numbers-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity#Structure_of_the_IMEI_and_IMEISV_.28IMEI_Software_Version.29

Good luck!